# Caesar Cipher Program from Text File

Tags: java

not asking for handouts on the completion of this project by any means. I have the program set up with the DecodeChar method to decode the provided file, which is juust a wall of jumbled text from the Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy in Caesar Cipher.  Just wanting a bit of guidance. The full code that I have so far, is as follows:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Boggs1
 */
public class Caesar 
{

private static Scanner sc;
private static FileWriter fw;
private static BufferedWriter bw;

public static char decodeChar(int n, char ch)
{
    int ord;
    if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
    {
        ord = ch - 'A';
        ord += n;
        ord %= 26;
        return (char)(ord + 'A');
    }
    else if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
    {
        ord = ch - 'a';
        ord += n;
        ord %= 26;
        return (char)(ord + 'a');
    }
    else
    {
        return ch;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Number of command-line arguments: " + args.length);
    File inputFile = new File("decode.txt");
    File outputFile = new File("decoded.txt");
    try 
    {
        sc = new Scanner(inputFile);
        int shift = sc.nextInt();
        String decoded = "";
        while( sc.hasNextLine() )
        {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            for(int i=0; i<line.length(); i++)
            {
                decoded += decodeChar(shift, line.charAt(i));                    
            }
            decoded += '\n';
        }
        System.out.println(decoded);
        try
        {
            fw = new FileWriter(outputFile);
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(decoded);
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

Both files; Decoded.txt and Decode.txt are in the Caesar package, but NetBeans is giving me an error saying that Decode.txt (the one with the cipher words) is not found. Is there a more efficient way to put the files into the program that I am just missing?

Comment: In your question, you say "Decode.txt" however, in your code it say "decode.txt." Is the file Decode, or decode? as that could make a difference.

Comment: Note that your way of reading and writing files is **legacy**. Use Javas new I/O API **NIO** instead. It revolves around the classes `Files`, `Paths` and `Path`.